# Is it possible to change Google Map styles after the map has been initialised?

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I understand how to initialise a map with custom styles like the following:

```
var styles =   [
    {
      featureType: "water",
      stylers: [
        { visibility: "on" },
        { color: "#ffffff" }
      ]
    }
  ];

var mapOptions = {
      zoom: 13,
      maxZoom: 15,
      minZoom: 12,
      center: new google.maps.LatLng(50.924229,-1.396841),
      disableDefaultUI: true,
      mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
      styles: styles
    };
    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), mapOptions);
```

But is it possible to change to another style once the map has already been initialised? For example changing the colours of the map when certain events are triggered?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Yes. just use

```
map.setOptions(mapOptions);
```

Answer (score 10):

Yes, create a new style object and then change the style by setting the option:
map.setOptions({styles: styles});